# VueJS: Call function from bootstrap/jQuery script includes in template/layout from a component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

i am very new to VueJS and want to build an Admin Dashboard for an existing bootstrap template (SB Admin Pro). I know there is a BootstrapVUE but we want to use the specified template that we purchased before. So this is not an option for me/us.

**My Goal:**
In our vue component we make an axios call to our backend to retrieve and show some data. If the call fails we want to call in the catch block a bootstrap function for toast to show some notification to the user (like: Error while fetching data from backend...). We included the bootstrap and jquery libraries from the template in the default index.html.

**The Problem:**
I don't know how to call the toasts (or other) functions from the vue component. In the template the call looks like this:
`$("#toastBasic").toast("show");`

Our index.html looks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="svote UG (haftungsbeschränkt)" />
    <script data-search-pseudo-elements defer src="js/font-awesome-5.11.2.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="./js/feather.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="nav-fixed">
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script defer src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Our vue component:

```
<template>
  <main>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 1rem; right: 1rem;">
    <!-- Toast container -->
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 1rem; right: 1rem;">
        <!-- Toast -->
        <div class="toast" id="toastBasic" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="5000">
            <div class="toast-header">
                <i data-feather="bell"></i>
                <strong class="mr-auto">Toast with Autohide</strong>
                <small class="text-muted ml-2">just now</small>
                <button class="ml-2 mb-1 close" type="button" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="toast-body">This is an example toast alert, it will dismiss automatically, or you can dismiss it manually.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
    <ContentHeader title="Blank" icon="fas fa-file" subtitle="A blank page to get you started!" />
    <div class="container-fluid mt-n10">
      <div v-if="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ error }}
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <Card cHeader="Eine Karte" class="col-md-12"> {{ contacts }}</Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  import ContentHeader from '../../components/ContentHeader'
  import Card from '../../components/Card'
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    name: "Contact",
    components: {
      ContentHeader,
      Card,

    },
    data() {
      return {
        contacts: null,
        error: null
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/v1/';
         axios.get(url + 'contsact')
            .then(response => {
              this.contacts = response.data
               console.log(response)}
            )
            .catch(error => {
                 console.log(error.response)
                $("#toastBasic").toast("show");
            });

    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `vue.config.js`, specify `jquery` as external (this tells webpack where to provide `jquery` from when it's imported in any component):

```
configureWebpack: {
  externals: {
    jquery: 'window.jQuery'
  }
}
```

Place all the `<script>`s you want loaded by the time Vue inits in your `public/index.html` page, in the `<head>` tag and remove their `defer` attribute. This includes any jquery plugin (or anything requiring/extending jquery) you might want to use in your Vue app (in your case, `bootstrap.min.js`).

The above will make it work when developing (in serve). You'll need to do the same for prod: Load jquery and any dependency before initing the Vue app.

Now you can safely use

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

in any component.

Webpack will place in `$` whatever `window.jQuery` is at the moment the component inits.

---

The above approach makes sure all required scripts are loaded before Vue inits (which is a bit extreme, but it makes sure there's no way you can call the jquery method before its dependencies are loaded).

If you don't want to wait for `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js` to load before you init your Vue app, a trick you could use is to assign jquery from `window` object just before you need it:

```
yourAlertMethod() {
  const $ = window.jQuery;
  $.toast()...
}
```

Obviously, you no longer have to move all the scripts in `<head>` and to remove their `defer`. This second method doesn't guarantee they would have already loaded before your method is first used. But your app inits faster.

---

Here's a [basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sara-t7mrk?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue).
I used the second method, `codesandbox.io` doesn't have support for `@vue/cli v3` hence `vue.config.js` doesn't work as in a Vue project created with `vue create`. Therefore, I had to use the second method.

The full list of dependecies you need to load before you call the `$(el).toast()` method:

- bootstrap.min.css
- jquery.js
- popper.js
- bootstrap.min.js

(see them in `public/index.html`). You can copy/paste them from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start).

Comment: Do i need the to import the bootstrap.min.js also ?
Because the toast function is in this file

Comment: Yep, `$.toast()` is a Bootstrap JS plugin, extending jQuery: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/#toastoptions

Comment: Ok, now i did the changes and the errors in the log disapper. But the toast didn't show up when i call in ```                 $("#toastBasic").toast("show");```in the mounted function of my component

Comment: Are you sure an element with `id="toastBasic"` exists in DOM? On the same note, are you sure there's only one element with this `id`? Is it a valid toast element? If you provide a [mcve], I'll be able to help further.

Comment: yes. The line looks like this ```<div class="toast" id="toastBasic" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="5000">``` as you can see in my initial post

Comment: Ok, I'll create a `codesandbox.io` working example starting from your code and document any other bugs I find along the way.

Comment: I can provide you the complete project: https://github.com/Selichio/vue-example
you can found the affected component under src/views/Contact

Comment: No need. I got it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sara-t7mrk?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Since you no longer see the js error, you probably haven't loaded all the Bootstrap dependencies as specified on their [Getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) page. For no specific reason, I assumed you read getting started before getting started with Bootstrap.

Comment: @D, you also have another problem: since you're loading the data from `localhost`, it's probably resolving quite fast. Before all bootstrap dependencies load. So your error happens before `$().toast` is available. On a live server, that might change. But still, it's safer to render your app after all toast deps loaded, since you might call it right after rendering the app.

Comment: oh damn... i found the error.. the toast didn't appear because of the surounding div. I think i copied the code twice -.- After removing the first div (over the Toast component comment) it works as expected

Comment: i must admit that i did not follow the instructions on the Getting started page because i took the resources from my purchased template

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: What did you mean with the bootstrap dependencies ? I moved the includes to the <head> area. So the dependencies should load before the request triggered? Or didn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214292/discussion-between-tao-and-dennis-se).

Answer (score 0):

You can get ref of the element and pass it to jQuery

```html
<div ref="toast" class="toast" id="toastBasic" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="5000">
```

```js
import $ from 'jQuery';

$(this.$refs.toast).toast("show");
```

I don't recommend that though.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!!
i tried it out but seams not working. I got the following error in console:
TypeError: ```jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).toast is not a function```

Comment: weird, what does `console.log(this.$refs);` display?